# Laravel не видит пакет

Tags: laravel, пакет

Здравствуйте проблема после обновления движка laravel с 5.4 до 5.8 не видит пакет, точнее не там его смотреть стал.
Выдает ошибку

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\Spirit1086\Dashboard\Http\Controllers\CmsController does not exist
```

мой composer.json

```
 "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Spirit1086\\Dashboard\\": "packages/spirit1086/dashboard/src",
        "Spirit1086\\Mabwidgets\\": "packages/spirit1086/mabwidgets/src"
    }
},
```

в CmsController namespace прописан верно и главное все работало до обновления движка

```
namespace Spirit1086\Dashboard\Http\Controllers;
```

composer dump-autoload, php artisan optimize делал, подскажите как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Прям именно такой неймспейс должен быть прописан? Где по твоему должен искаться файл, если все прописано верно?

Comment: До обновления искал верно, а как должен быть прописан?

Comment: Обновил движок заново, после запустил :  php artisan route:clear

php artisan config:clear

php artisan cache:clear сработало, хотя после установки у меня php artisan optimize прописан и в консоле вижу что выполнялся